# Incompatible block pointer types issue ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

incompatible block pointer types sending

```
(void) start
{
   //some code
    __block NSError *dependentError = nil;
    [self.dependencies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomBaseOperationLoader *operation, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

   if (operation.operationError != nil) {
    dependentError = [operation.operationError copy];
    *stop = YES;
      }
   }
      ];

}
```

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void
>   (^)(CustomBaseOperationLoader *__strong, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to
>   parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(NSOperation * _Nonnull __strong,
>   NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)'